# Setting a gulp src path?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm using gulp aws publish to upload files to S3.

```
return gulp.src('/prod/assets/**/*')
```

The above is the path to my assets, it uploads everything in the assets folder, but how can I specify the path to include the assets folder?

```
return gulp.src('/prod/**/*')
```

This will not work as it will include other folders inside the production folder and not just the assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `base` option:

```
return gulp.src('./prod/assets/**/*', {base:'./prod'})
```

If you don't explicitly provide a `base` option everything before the first glob is used as the base. In your case `./prod/assets` was used as the base which is why the `assets` folder itself was not created.